# How to disable disappearing of Stencil Brush while navigating viewport in Texture Paint Mode?

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, texture-painting, navigation

I've got 3D scanned model, it has complicated geometry.
I UV Unwrapped it, now it's time for painting.

I've shot several photos of the real object, and I started to paint the 3D object using photos of the real object.

That's maybe one of not so common situations: the 3D model has the same geometry as real one, so it looks like it would be easy to paint it with stencil brush, but I'm having very hard time with this, most of because of every time I'm rotating, panning, zooming the viewport - the stencil image disappeares, it makes almost imposible to perfectly match viewport with these photos.

Can I disable the disappearing of the Stencil while navigating the viewport?

Also, is there a way to zoom the viewport without changing perspective? (such as "Size" parameter in Camera options? I know I can assing camera to viewport, but that's not what I am asking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using only the Stencil Brush, you can use the old method of multiple UV layered images projected from different views and then use the Clone tool in the 3d viewport to paint from the source layers in the final texture layer. After you get the bulk of your paint finished, you can then use the Stencil Brush to fix areas that need cleanup.